# VMware fusion cannot ping the guest VM

Tags: vmware, vmware-fusion

I have some issue with the network configuration of VMware fusion.
I am not able to ping the guest os (Ubuntu) from the host (MacOS Mojave).

Is someone have an idea to how configure the network settings ?

"Share with my Mac" or "Private to my Mac" ?

Is there some other stuf to configure ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the issue.

My VM had a fixed ip configure and i needed to change the VNET_1_HOSTONLY_SUBNET parameter of the /Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/networking file

Comment: Hi Maitre, May i know what value the `VNET_1_HOSTONLY_SUBNET ` should be?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your update. I had the same issue, guests connected to the "Private to my Mac" network couldn't ping (or reach other ports/services) each other or the Mac.

To resolve this the brute force way, I simply shut down VMware Fusion, then via terminal:

```
cd /Library/Preferences/
mkdir bak
sudo mv vmnet* bak/
sudo mv network* bak/
```

Following this, started VMware Fusion, edited the network adapters for my VMs to ensure that they were still attached to the correct networks and started them up. The VMs attached to "Private to my Mac" were now able to reach each other over that network.

Note, that this method "deleted" any custom networks that I had in place and I had to recreate those.